# Is BitBucket cloud version of source code repo along with Bamboo for CI/CD?

Tags: bitbucket, slack, bamboo

I'm new to Bamboo and currently learning & using the Bamboo as a standalone server in my company. There I can see the much-advanced options like creating the Build Plans, separate deployment projects based on different environments and also can integrate with notifications and triggers.

I wanted to do a lot of research and learning by myself at home so I was looking for a cloud-based version of Bamboo which I can straight away use to perform similar task like creating build plans, etc. I do not see anything cloud version of Bamboo but I can see BitBucket (cloud-based). What I know is that it is a source code repository like GitHub and GitLab and it has integration with inbuilt CI/CD.

Q1. Is BitBucket a cloud version of source code repository plus Bamboo?
Q2. If not, then do we have cloud version of Bamboo with exact options like build plans, deployment projects, etc
Q3. Also, I'm looking if there is any Bot which I can use like SlackBot or DeployBot to invoke or trigger the Bamboo Build Plan with a chat command? Slack I'm familiar but not DeployBot. I can get the Bamboo build notifications to my Slack channel but not the other way around.

I'm learning and doing research & development hence required clarification on my doubts from experts in this DevOps field to show me the right path.

Please suggest as I'm looking for setting up Bamboo with Bot instructing my build plans.

Thank you

Doing hands-on experience in company on Bamboo and learning as much as I can and playing around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo Cloud was discontinued in January 2017. Bitbucket Cloud can still notify your Bamboo instance via webhook, assuming you configure Bamboo and your firewall and the webhook properly, or you can use [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) for the all-in-one approach.

You can also use Bitbucket Server if you'd prefer to keep everything behind the firewall.